# Redis Server Configuration for high performance

Tags: java, redis

I made a VM on ubutnu with 8gb ram and configured maxmemory=4294967296 and maxclients 10000 in redis.conf file and contained dump.rdb file inside `/opt/redis` folder then after making 1.6 gb dump.rdb file it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:115)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:133)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:202)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connect
ion.java:285)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:184
)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.set(Jedis.java:63)
        at mypack.Test6.main(Test6.java:37)
```

Please suggest what should I do for the same....
Waiting for response...........

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430324/redis-error-oom-command-not-allowed-when-used-memory-maxmemory