# Redis keep throwing Out Of Memory (OOM) Error

Tags: node.js, redis, redis-cluster

I am using node js to store my data in Redis. I amusing HashSet to store Redis data and using HSETNX command. but when I am sending a continuous request to the Redis server I am getting the following error:

```
{ ReplyError: OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
   at parseError (/opt/built-flow/built-api-express/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:193:12)
   at parseType (/opt/built-flow/built-api-express/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:303:14)
 command: 'HSETNX'
```

any idea what this error means? and How I resolved this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug the error "OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'" in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430324/how-to-debug-the-error-oom-command-not-allowed-when-used-memory-maxmemory)

Comment: thanks but not able to understand what is the solution this?

Comment: @ponury-kostek my Redis showing used_memory_human:4.81G and maxmemory_human:4.81G does this cause this issue?

Comment: Increase Redis memory size or set key expiry if not done.

Comment: but what is the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you trying to save more data in terms of memory than Redis is can handle. Take a look here [Out of memory issues](https://ma.ttias.be/redis-oom-command-not-allowed-used-memory-maxmemory/#:%7E:text=The%20OOM%20command%20not%20allowed,using%20the%20redis%20CLI%20tool.)